# Using an ActiveX into C#

Tags: c#, activex

I need to communicate orders to an Agilent centrifuge VSpin through an ActiveX interface.

I've successfully installed the ActiveX.dll and I'm now able to add it as a reference in my Visual Studio.

I'm stuck here since I have no idea how to communicate with it ? I tried this :

```
// Others using;
using CentrifugeLib;

namespace TestMyCentri
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Centrifuge l_centri = new Centrifuge();

      l_centri.CloseDoor();

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

It compiles but cannot run it... I think I need to import the methods to access them but I can't find a simple example about how to do so...

Any help or tutorial would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add reference in following way, hope you have done this,

1. Open the windows form file that you want to add an Activex control.

   1. Right click on any tool on the tool box.
   2. That menu contains "Choose Items".
   3. Click on it and you can see the COM Components tab on the pop up
      window.
   4. Select any COM component that you want to add.
   5. Then it appears on the tool box.
   6. Drag and drop it on to the form.

Then follow up with this article to know how to use

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27219&seqNum=9

Comment: I don't want to access it from a form but from my code. The ActiveX file will help me communicate with a Centrifuge, that's it... I want to create some kind of driver in C#, if you know what I mean...